# build ffmpeg library with a sample project and use it in eclipse on Linux operating system

Tags: android, c++, ffmpeg, android-ndk

I want to ffmpeg project in eclipse on linux operating system
I am following the link: http://dmitrydzz-hobby.blogspot.in/2012/04/how-to-build-ffmpeg-and-use-it-in.html
I have successfully add the ndk in eclipse but it still shows some error in loading the ffmpeg library

My logcat contains error:

```
Building file: ../jni/ffmpeg/libavcodec/x86/dct32_sse.asm
Invoking: GCC Assembler
as  -o "jni/ffmpeg/libavcodec/x86/dct32_sse.o" "../jni/ffmpeg/libavcodec/x86/dct32_sse.asm"
../jni/ffmpeg/libavcodec/x86/dct32_sse.asm: Assembler messages:
../jni/ffmpeg/libavcodec/x86/dct32_sse.asm:1: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `*'
../jni/ffmpeg/libavcodec/x86/dct32_sse.asm:2: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `*'
../jni/ffmpeg/libavcodec/x86/dct32_sse.asm:3: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `*'
../jni/ffmpeg/libavcodec/x86/dct32_sse.asm:4: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `*'
../jni/ffmpeg/libavcodec/x86/dct32_sse.asm:5: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `*'
../jni/ffmpeg/libavcodec/x86/dct32_sse.asm:6: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `*'
../jni/ffmpeg/libavcodec/x86/dct32_sse.asm:7: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `*'
../jni/ffmpeg/libavcodec/x86/dct32_sse.asm:7: Error: no such instruction: `you can redistribute it and/or'
../jni/ffmpeg/libavcodec/x86/dct32_sse.asm:8: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `*'
../jni/ffmpeg/libavcodec/x86/dct32_sse.asm:9: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `*'
../jni/ffmpeg/libavcodec/x86/dct32_sse.asm:9: Error: no such instruction: `either'
```